# How to make variable visible from one function in another? (JavaScript. jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I have socket.io application code and variable timer = 1000;

```
socket.on('get data', function(question){
        socket.emit('chat message', $(this).val());
        var timer = 1000;
});
```

That part of code send input value to the server and from server to another clients (websockets, you know).
But when I try to console.log my timer variable, I get an error " timer is not defined".

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        console.log(timer);
        $('#results').append($('<li>').text(msg));
        return false;
});
```

So how I can make variable visible in jQuery from one function in another? Without sending it to the server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should send data inside an object like this:

**EMIT**

```
socket.on('get data', function(question){
     var data = {
       input: $(this).val(),
       timer: 1000
     }
     socket.emit('chat message', data);
});
```

**ON**

```
socket.on('chat message', function(data){
     console.log(data.timer);
     $('#results').append($('<li>').text(data.input));
     return false;
});
```

Comment: @BimBam no probz :)